# How do I write out a list as a narrative?

Tags: passive-voice, narration

How do I write this out as a narrative in a small amount of words?

"Add reagent A to each of four test tubes, then
To test tube 1 add H2O
To test tube 2 add urea standard solution
To test tube 3 add plasma A
To test tube 4 add plasma B"

I've tried "Reagent A was added to four test tubes, and then to one of each H2O, urea standard solution, plasma A, and plasma B respectively." But am not sure if this makes sense and describes what is actually being done?

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is confusing you? Maybe try posting what you've attempted.

Comment: Reagent A was added to four test tubes, and then to one of each H2O, urea standard solution, plasma A, and plasma B respectively.

I'm not sure if this makes sense and describes what is actually being done?

Comment: You might want to add that to your question instead of as a comment. What about that attempt do you think works and doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure if it reads as all four solutions being added to each of the four test tubes rather than it being just one solution per test tube.

Comment: I read that as one test tube getting H2O added, one getting the urea solution, etc... but the "then to one of each..." is awkward. I might have said "then to each, one of...", though that leaves open the theoretical possibility that one or more additive was used multiple times and one or more not at all.

Comment: Your first suggestion is stronger, though you would need to clean up the punctuation and capitalization a little. The best I came up with was, `"Add Reagent A to each of four test tubes. Then add a different, single additive to each. The four additives should be H2O, urea standard solution, plasma A, and plasma B."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Four test tubes of reagent A were prepared, to receive H<sub>2</sub>O, urea standard solution, plasma A or plasma B respectively.
>
> (20 words)

*Adding* is generally used to introduce one reagent to another. You wouldn't generally *add* a reagent to a test tube, so I *prepared* them. We're then talking about the test tubes, not "reagent A", so again the test samples are not added to the test tube: the test tubes need to do something — so they *receive* the samples.

If you really want to use *added* as a positive action which you did, I suggest

> Four test tubes of reagent A were prepared, to which were added H<sub>2</sub>O, urea standard solution, plasma A or plasma B respectively.
>
> (22 words)

*Respectively* is a way of [associating two lists](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34843/use-of-respectively), so it's slightly odd here but it's probably the only way of associating each of the samples with each of the four test tubes. Using *each* ("to each of which") is definitely wrong as you are then adding all four samples to all four test tubes.

Answer (score 0):

Reagent A was added to four test tubes. Then H2O, urea standard solution, plasma A, or plasma B was added to the four respectively.

(24 words)