# The use of respectively

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-usage

I already read several posts on this forum, for example: [Use of "respectively"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34843/use-of-respectively). I was however wondering about a specific use case:

> Items 1, 3, 4, and 6 dealt with motivation directly, feelings of guilt, enjoyment, and personality, respectively.

vs

> In respective order, items 1, 3, 4, and 6 dealt with motivation directly, feelings of guilt, enjoyment, and personality.

What would be preferred? For me it feels that the 2nd is clearer.

Comment: "In respective order" is not idiomatic. Better: "Items 1, 3, 4 and 6 dealt respectively with W, X, Y, Z". That sets up the interpretive structure in advance, so the reader doesn't have to backtrack.

Comment: That is indeed much more intuitive, I had not thought of that. Thank you

Comment: Out of interest, would 'dealt with respectively' also be correct? (i.e. small reordering of the words)

Comment: Not really. 'Respectively' signals that two lists are in the same order--that 'splits' your second list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to this question here, [StoneyB](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/24489/stoneyb) wrote:

> "In respective order" is not idiomatic. Better: "Items 1, 3, 4 and 6 dealt
>   respectively with W, X, Y,
>   Z". That sets up the interpretive structure in
>   advance, so the reader
>   doesn't have to backtrack.